# Which data structures and algorithms book should I buy?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I know C and C++ and I have some experience with Java, but I don't know too much about Algorithms and Data Structures.

I did a search on Amazon, but I don't know what book should I choose. I don't want a book which put its basis only on the theoretic part; I want the practical part too (probably more than the theoretical one :) ).

I don't want the code to be implemented in a certain language, but if is in Java, probably I would happier. :)

Comment: `<The Algorithm Design Manual 2nd>` it's fun and practical !

Answer (score 31):

[image]
<sub>(source: [wikimedia.org](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/4/41/Clrs3.jpeg/220px-Clrs3.jpeg))</sub>

Don't buy any book use

### [MIT OCW](https://web.archive.org/web/20100414015823/http://ocw.mit.edu:80/OcwWeb/Electrical-Engineering-and-Computer-Science/6-046JFall-2005/CourseHome/)

.

Comment: Personally, I things it's too math, not very to understand.

Comment: I skipped the math part

Comment: Don't you need the book to do the readings for this course though?

Comment: Too much of a dry book. Its huge and definitely not for beginners. and way not suitable for self learners.

Comment: "Don't buy any book..." I've got news for you. Not everyone has to like the same book that you like. There are many other good books and Youtube videos which often explain things better than CLRS and its associated MIT OCW videos.

Comment: @Telenoobies - which parts did you skip and which ones did you read ? thanks.

Comment: @Borat The proofs mostly. And went straight into the algorithm.

Answer (score 19):

[Introduction to Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262032937) by Cormen et. al. is a standard introductory algorithms book, and is used by many universities, including my own. It has pretty good coverage and is very approachable.

And [anything by Robert Sedgewick](http://www.amazon.com/Robert-Sedgewick/e/B000AQ4JCO/ref=sr_ntt_srch_lnk_1?_encoding=UTF8&qid=1268482603&sr=1-1) is good too.

Comment: CLRS does not feel very approachable to me for 100% self study. It is probably approachable for very intelligent folks like you who can make it to Facebook or such. But, thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 6):

I think introduction to Algorithms is the reference books, and a must have for any serious programmer.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms

Other fun book is The algorithm design manual http://www.algorist.com/. It covers more sophisticated algorithms.

I can't not mention The art of computer programming of Knuth
http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/taocp.html

Comment: Have you read the full CLRS book ? Was CLRS the only learning resource you used, or did you have other books, youtube, college class etc ?

Answer (score 5):

If you want the algorithms to be implemented specifically in Java then there is Mitchell Waite's Series book "Data Structures & Algorithms in Java".  It starts from basic data structures like linked lists, stacks and queues, and the basic algorithms for sorting and searching.  Working your way through it you will eventually get to Tree data structures, Red-Black trees, 2-3 trees and Graphs.

All-in-all its not an extremely theoretical book, but if you just want an introduction in a language you are familiar with then its a good book.  At the end of the day, if you want a deeper understanding of algorithms you're going to have to learn some of the more theoretical concepts, and read one of the classics, like  Cormen/Leiserson/Rivest/Stein's Introduction to Algorithms.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't need in a complete reference to the most part of algorithms and data structures that are in use and just want to get acquainted with common techniques I would recommend something more lightweight than Cormen, Sedgewick or Knuth. I think, [Algorithms and Data Structures](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130220051) by N. Wirth is not as bad choice even in spite of it was printed far ago.